# Redirection of ID in Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a question. because im working on a PagedList where i need to Paginate the GridView of my Page but when i press the Next Button . I got Redirected in a Null Field

This is my Snippet:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "UserIndex", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, viewEvent = ViewBag.EventId, userId = UserLogInInfoModel.UserId }, null)
```

I want To be redirected on this :

```
/User/EventDetails?viewEvent=55&userId=12&page=1
```

But i was redirected to this:

```
/User/EventDetails?page=1
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try removing the `null` parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next >", "EventDetails", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, viewEvent = ViewBag.EventId, userId = UserLogInInfoModel.UserId })
```

Comment: Same Result sir :( Redirected to different page

Comment: @RenTao Try updated code, also share your `RouteConfig.cs` content

Comment: i dont have routeConfig.cs

Comment: @RenTao It will be present inside your `App_Start` folder.

Comment: i dont even see an App_Start Folder here either

Comment: Thanks for Helping me . . This Memory of mine. Added The statement at the Wrong Page. . Thanks BTW